What would the weather and climate be like on an Earth-size Mars with an atmospheric pressure of 1 atm?
Assuming the planet still has the same atmospheric composition as the real-world Mars (95% CO2, 3% N2, and 1.3% Ar) and has a global temperature of 284K (10.85°C) based on the answer to my previous question, for which I thank the user for that. With the abundance of carbon dioxide and a warmer temperature, how might the weather behave in various regions of Mars?

Given the range of weathers and climates that exist on earth, what makes you think that this question is sufficiently focused to be suitable for this site?

Probably not much - the equatorial wind circulation would be likely the same. Most important difference is that there would be no water, so no rains. Also no clouds.

@jdunlop I believe this is different because this question discusses about the topic of the weather and other meteorological phenomenon, instead of knowing simply about the global temperature as I stated above.
